# Drupal 9 - Output Views "Content: Link to Content" url to views-view-unformatted....html.twig template

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-views, drupal-9

I am trying to output the url alias from Views "Content: Link to Content" in a Twig template of the format `views-view-unformatted....html.twig`. The url alias outputs successfully in the Views preview similar to `/path1/article`. Forums suggest `{{ fields.view_node.content }}` should work but it doesn't in my case.

`views-view-unformatted....html.twig` is as below

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 */
#}

{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  
{{row.content['#row']._entity.title[0].value}} ***returns value for title
/node/{{row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}}" ***returns nid 
{{ fields.view_node.content }} ***doesn't work
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }} ***crashes page
{% endfor %}
```

I've tried variations like:

```
{{row.content['#row']._entity.url[0].value}}
{{row.content['#row']._entity.view_node[0].value}}
{{row.content['#row']._entity.alias[0].value}}
```

with no success.

It looks like my template doesn't have a fields variable as mentioned at this [thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208201/how-to-get-each-field-value-in-views-views-unformatted-view-machine-name-html-t) so how would I go about enabling one? I use the [Drupal Barrio theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio)

Would love some help. Thanks

Added:

When I do a var dump I see"

```
+field: &52 array:7 [▼
            "view_node" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityLink {#9889 ▶}
            "title" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10494 ▶}
            "nid" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10357 ▶}
            "body" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10827 ▶}
            "field_featured_image" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10503 ▶}
            "field_subheading" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10375 ▶}
            "field_news_tags" => Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\EntityField {#10824 ▶}
          ]
```

The link relates to view mode is an Entity Link instead of an Entity Field.

I tried all these variation but none rendered the url/alias

```
#view
{{row.content['#view'].field.view_node[0].value}}
{{row.content['#view'].field.view_node[0].content}}
{{row.content['#view'].field.view_node.content}}
{{row.content['#view'].field.view_node.value}}
{{row.content['#view'].link.view_node[0].content}}
{{row.content['#view'].link.view_node.content}}
#row
{{row.content['#row'].field.view_node[0].value}}
{{row.content['#row'].field.view_node[0].content}}
{{row.content['#row'].field.view_node.content}}
{{row.content['#row'].field.view_node[0].value}}
{{row.content['#row'].link.view_node[0].content}}
{{row.content['#row'].link.view_node.content}}
```

.tried `fields.` (plural) too with no luck

Comment: if all else fails I can use `/node/{{row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}}` and the Redirect module to redirect from `/node/[num]` to alias. Was hoping this would be a lot easier. Especially for this Drupal 9 beginner

Comment: You said that  : {{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }} ***crashes page, what is the error?

Comment: Hi, Error is "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." - blank white page. Thanks

Comment: `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}` Error: Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "node" for route "entity.node.canonical" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 203 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

Comment: I tried `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}` in a test `views-view-fields.html.twig` template and it successfully returns a url path. `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}` crashes `views-view-fields.html.twig` . Unfortunately ``{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}`` causes `unformatted....html.twig` to crash. Perhaps a variance of `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}` is needed.

Comment: Introducing "row" into the syntax as per `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}` seems helpful. Maybe an issues with some Manage Display setting in Drupal Admin? Using `path('entity.node.canonical', { 'node' : row.nid}) }}` causes `unformatted....html.twig` to crash with same error:  `Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\InvalidParameterException: Parameter "node" for route "entity.node.canonical" must match "\d+" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 203 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).`

Answer (score 0):

You said that {{row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}} return your the id of your node.

So instead of

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}
```

You should replace node.id by the id of the node in the row content :

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}) }}
```

That's why your previous try failed, because in this context {{ node.id }} doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. `{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}) }` crashes the page. I get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." but `{{row.content['#row']._entity.nid[0].value}}` works for returning id, however I am looking to return the url/alias.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for this beginner courtesy of: [link](https://www.codimth.com/blog/web/drupal/accessing-views-row-fields-inside-views-view-unformattedhtmltwig-drupal-8)

Use this code in views-view-unformatted.WHATEVER.html.twig

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a view of unformatted rows.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - title: The title of this group of rows. May be empty.
 * - rows: A list of the view's row items.
 *   - attributes: The row's HTML attributes.
 *   - content: The row's content.
 * - view: The view object.
 * - default_row_class: A flag indicating whether default classes should be
 *   used on rows.
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted()
 */
#}
{% if title %}
    <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
{% endif %}
{% for key,row in rows %}
    {% set row_classes = [
        default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ] %}
  
         
<a href="{{ view.style_plugin.getField(key, 'view_node')|render|striptags|trim }}">Link to node</a>
         
{% endfor %}
```

Notice he uses the term "key" in `{% for key,row in rows %}`
As this is being added to a link I added `|render|striptags|trim` to the end because with Twig Debug module enabled it was messing up the link by wrapping debug comments around it.

Hope it helps somebody else out! I also hope it's a decent/acceptable solution!?